# При больших скоростях объекты проходят сквозь друг-друга [решено]

Tags: c#, unity3d

С Box2D это решалось `setBullet(true)`.

Как такое сделать в Unity? У меня очень быстро вращаются объекты, и нужно чтобы ещё один объект взаимодействовал с ними, а не проходил насквозь

Более подробно:
 есть квадрат с `boxCollider2d` и `rigidBody2D`. Ещё есть под ним длинный прямоугольник с тем же самым, плюс к нему прицеплен скрипт для вращения по оси Z. Получается, что квадрат падает на прямоугольник, и при вращении прямоугольника скользит по нему. Так вот, при резком повороте прямоугольника квадрат проходит сквозь него. Думаю, это происходит из-за того, что коллизии просто не успевают обработаться. В *box2d* `setBullet(true)` говорила движку, что этот объект нужно про считывать точнее.

P.s. итак, это было из-за того, что я поворачивал прямоугольник через `transform.rotation`, а нужно было через `rigidBody2d.rotation`.

Comment: А можно что-то наглядное?) Что у вас есть, как оно выглядит.  И как правильно. Потому что непонятно причем тут вращающийся объект и прохождение сквозь

Comment: Ноутбук далеко, так что только дать описание) есть квадрат с boxCollider2d и rigidBody2D. Ещё есть под ним длинный прямоугольник с тем же самым, плюс к нему прицеплен скрипт для вращения по оси Z. Получается, что квадрат падает на прямоугольник, и при вращении прямоугольника скользит по нему. Так вот, при резком повороте прямоугольника квадрат проходит сквозь него. Думаю, это происходит из-за  того, что коллизии просто не успевают обработаться. В box2d setBullet(true) говорила движку, что этот объект нужно про считывать точнее.

Comment: Странно как-то) Но, в любом случае, если есть какой-то теоретический код, который вы наваяли - потом добавьте в вопрос. Возможно что-то в нем не совсем корректно (во вращении или отскоке и пр.)

Comment: Сорри, не смог удержаться - но это не баг, а фича. Вот она же в исполнении Флеша: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8C1VLmQxgo

Comment: То, что вы хотите, называется "непрерывной проверкой столкновений" или "continious collision detection". Быстрое пробитие этого по гуглу показало [вот это](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html). Если разберётесь, можете написать ответ сами, я не обижусь.

Comment: Спасиб, это то, что искал. Но даже так проходит сквозь. Чтож, придётся ограничивать скорость вращения... а с багофичей отличная идея, жаль что тут не подходит)

Comment: Волшебства не бывает. Если проходит насквозь даже с этим, это либо баг который надо репортить, либо ошибка пользователя и надо быть внимательнее.

Comment: Вы натолкнули меня на мысль - для вращения использовал 'transform.Rotate (0, 0, 5)', может, дело в том, что угол перемещается на 5, и на конце прямоугольника квадрат попадает в промежуток между? Но поменял код на 'transform.Rotate (0, 0, Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition.y);', и все равно проходит насквозь. Скрипт только один использую, в нем только вращение.Ставил-убирал "is kinematic"-прямоугольник.В RigidBody2D есть только Discrete и Continuous, Continuous Dynamic отсутствует.Сейчас попробую заменить у себя на "не 2D".Где-то натыкался на изменение параметра в настройках Unity, но не хочу так

Comment: А ведь я говорил, что нужен ваш код и детальное описание действий, но нет....вот и мучайтесь

Comment: Пустая сцена Unity3D. 1)Добавляю 2D Object -> Sprite(и выбираю его рисунок), 2) к нему через AddComponent цепляю RigidBody2D и BoxCollider2D. 3) Во вкладке Transform меняю Scale.x и Scale.y на 10 - это все квадрат. Повторяю 1, 2 и 3 опять, но теперь Scale.x = 50 - это прямоугольник. Еще с помощью AddComponent цепляю к прясоугольнику скрипт: `if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) // левая кнопка мыши
 transform.Rotate(0,0,5);
  
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) //правая кнопка мыши
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -5);`. Теперь по нажатию ЛКМ прямо-к вращается в одну сторону, по ПКМ - в другую

Comment: Квадрат размещаю в position = (0,2), прямоугольник в position = (0,0). Прямоугольнику в RigidBody2D ставлю `isKininematic(true)`. Запускаю сцену, только на квадрат действует сила тяжести. Теперь жму ПКМ, прямоугольник вращается, квадрат съезжает. жму ЛКМ, прямоугольник вращается обратно и должен подкинуть квадрат, но то ли прям-к, то ли квадрат, часто проходят сквозь друг друга (особенно если у прямоугольника поставить Scale.x очень большой). Теперь про изменение настроек в самой юнити - физика будет точнее просчитываться у всех объектов, а не у нужных, и все станет очень-очень печально

Comment: Это происходит потому, что кадры не успевают за вашей скоростью, чтобы такого не было, позиции нужно запоминать. 
Напишите в `Start` методе `oldPos = transform.position;` и в конце метода `Update` - `oldPos = transform.position;`. И работайте с ней спокойно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Как реализовано движение обьекта? Если оно реализовано через изменение трансформ.позишн -- то это вполне ожидаемый результат. Ведь при быстром вращении обьект будет тупо проходить сквозь стенку коллижна.
2. Как и казал КингПис -- нужно попробовать донастроить Interpolate и Collision Detection в Rigidbody. Но это вряд ли поможет, если реализовано через трансформ.позишн

Answer (score 5):

Если у вас физика работает и мелкий объект проскакивает через другой объект, то попробуйте поменять в объекте `Rigidbody2D` параметры `Interpolate` и `Collision Detection`, обычно помогает.)